# Runtime and compile-time checking of type values

Tags: c++, c++17

C++ is a strongly-typed language.  This can (and should) be used for our benefits.  For example, instead of writing a function like this:

```
File* getFileById(uint8_t id);
```

It would be better to have something like this:

```
File* getFileById(FileID id);
```

In the former case, if, for example, the **value** of the file id can only be between 0 and 31, this would need to be verified by the `getFileById` function and every other function which takes a file id.

However, in the latter case, the **value** can be (or at least I believe so) checked directly by the `FileID` type itself.  In this way, you cannot create a `FileID` type without its value being valid.  In other words, having an instance of the `FileID` type ensures that it has a valid value.

This leads me to my question.  How do I actually check/enforce the value in FileID.

The one option I know of would be to use exceptions within the constructor like so:

```
class FileID
{
    using value_type = uint8_t;

public:
    constexpr FileID(value_type v) : _v(v)
    {
        if (v > 31) throw std::invalid_argument{"v must be < 32"};
    }
private:
    value_type _v;
};
```

But there are a couple problems with this design.

First, what if the code cannot use exceptions (e.g., in an embedded system because of the overhead)?

Second, this only checks values at runtime.  I am wondering if there is a way to check the value at compile-time in cases where the value is known at compile-time.  For example:

```
constexpr auto kMyFileID = FileID{33};
```

Should throw a **compile-time** error because 33 is not within the valid range of values for a `FileID`.

Are there any solutions to these two problems?

Comment: Make the private constructor, and use static named constructors? E.g. something like `std::optional<FileID> FileID::try_from(uint_8)` for the first case?

Comment: If your program cannot use exceptions and your constructor must fail, just `abort()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `constexpr` function may or may not be executed at compile time, so you cannot read the value of the variable and use it in e.g. a `static_assert` inside the constructor body, so if you want to enter the constructor with a potentially invalid value, you need to use a special state of the `FileID` to mark it as invalid, e.g.

```
class FileID
{
    uint8_t m_id;

    static constexpr uint8_t invalid_id = 0xff;
    static constexpr uint8_t max_id = 31;
public:
    constexpr FileID(uint8_t id)
        : m_id(id)
    {
        if (id > max_id)
        {
            m_id = invalid_id;
        }
    }

    constexpr explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return m_id != invalid_id;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!() const
    {
        return m_id == invalid_id;
    }
};

constexpr FileID f1 = 32;
static_assert(!f1); // file id is invalid
```

If you always use compile time constants to create the `FileID` objects, you could instead introduce a function for creating the `FileID`s that uses a template parameter to pass the id; template parameters can be used in a `static_assert`, but you won't be able to use values that are not compile time constants with this approach.

```
class FileID
{
    uint8_t m_id;
    static constexpr uint8_t max_id = 31;
    
    consteval FileID(uint8_t id)
        : m_id(id)
    {
    }
public:

    template<uint8_t id>
    static consteval FileID create()
    {
        static_assert(id <= max_id, "file ids larger than 31 are disallowed");
        return id;
    }

    
};

constexpr auto f1 = FileID::create<31>(); // ok
constexpr auto f2 = FileID::create<32>(); // compiler error
```

---

Note: You may be able get better autocompletion with an approach similar to the second approach that instead uses an template object `template<uint8_t id> struct FileIDCreationToken {};` which would allow you to create a template constructor restricting the possible tokens allowed to be passed via a concept, but the error messages in this case are not as good as with the template function; You may find a suitable IDE though that directly highlights

```
inline constexpr uint8_t max_file_id = 31;

template<uint8_t id>
struct FileIDCreationToken : std::integral_constant<uint8_t, id> {};

template<class T>
struct is_valid_file_id_creation_token : std::false_type {};

template<uint8_t id>
struct is_valid_file_id_creation_token<FileIDCreationToken<id>> : std::bool_constant<(id <= max_file_id)> {};

template<class T>
concept valid_file_id_creation_token = is_valid_file_id_creation_token<T>::value;

class FileID
{
    uint8_t m_id;

public:

    template<valid_file_id_creation_token T>
    consteval FileID(T)
        : m_id(T::value)
    {
    }

};

constexpr FileID f1 = FileIDCreationToken<31>{}; // ok
constexpr FileID f2 = FileIDCreationToken<32>{}; // probably the IDE complains about this even before compilation
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type that is FileID that might look something like this:

```
class FileID {
private:
    uint_8 unique_id;

public:
    FileID(std::fstream& fs, std::string_view filename) {
        // Verify the the validity of this file and set its id
        unique_id = //"generated value within specified range"
    } 
};
```

You could add a simple flag variable that gets set upon successful creation of this object along with an accessor function might then look like this...

```
class FileID {
private:
     uint_8 unique_id;
     bool isValid;

public:
     FileID(std::fstream& fs, std::string_view filename) {
         // same as before
         unique_id = ...

         if ( unique_id is NOT within range )
             isValid = false;
         isValid = true;
     }

     bool isValid() const { return isValid; }
 };
```

Then any function or code that would use this object can always use this method without having to know the internal state of the object. This would also all the object to be constructed even though the ID might be invalid. This would prevent having to thrown an exception where exceptions can't be used. This would also allow the capability to discard or prevent the use of the object by calling its `isValid()` member function through testing the validity of the object.

Now as to make this testable at compile time... I'm not 100% sure but I'd think something like this might work, we could just change the `isValid()` function to a `constexpr` function and use it within a `constexpr if` statement where needed...

```
class FileID {
private:
    uint_8 unique_id;
    bool isValid;

public:
    FileID(std::fstream& fs, std::string_view filename) {
        // same as before
        unique_id = ...

        if ( unique_id is NOT within range )
            isValid = false;
        isValid = true;
     }

     constexpr bool isValid() const { return isValid; }
};
```

And then in some other function we could use it something like this:

```
void foo(FileID id) {
    if constexpr(id.isValid() ) { //... }
}
```

This might help you to achieve your desired functionality or goal. You would have to experiment and test it out within your own environment.

Comment: I've seen this a few times in production code.  My main problem with the "isValid" idea is that, doesn't it break the whole concepts of object/class invariants.  Have an instance of something implies that it is valid (e.g., if I have a ball, it must actually be a valid ball).  But a FileID that can be "invalid" isn't really a FileID at all...

Comment: Here's a good article I found as to why not to use isValid and some solutions: https://arne-mertz.de/2021/09/isvalid-establish-invariants-avoid-zombies/

Comment: @PatrickWright I understand what you're saying, yet when it comes to precompiled code and trying to verify something that may not be able to be until during runtime is kind of an xy problem, especially if it involves opening, reading, writing, and closing the file. You did state that during compile that the value is known so that does help. If using templates in this situation that value has to be a known constant... And for not using that `isValid()` type method. Then maybe your could template this class that takes a range<min, max> as it's template argument. ...

Comment: @PatrickWright However, the idea with the `isValid()` method belonging to the class object would all you to call it on any instance of the object that is created in any other code block or scope.

Comment: @PatrickWright Based on the article that you shared a link to, I found this to be close to what you're looking for: "The solution to this conundrum is to make the constructor private and have a static factory method in the class that is responsible to create the object. If it succeeds, it should return the created object, and if not, it returns something else to indicate the failure." under the Alternatives to Exceptions section.